# Escape WordPress's HTML characters in the_content();

Tags: php, html, facebook, wordpress, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to create a custom Facebook share button on a WordPress theme

```
<a title="Facebook This" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[title]=MY%20TITLE%20-%20<?php the_title(); ?>&p[summary]=<?php the_content(); ?>&p[url]=<?php the_permalink(); ?>&p[images][0]=<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/logo.png" target="_blank">Facebook This</a>
```

I have everything working splendidly except that Facebook insists on displaying the HTML characters in the description:

```
<h3>Intro</h3><p>it shows all the tags here and it won't stop!!!</p>...
```

It does this with the_excerpt() as well.

Does anyone know a quick way to remove the html tags for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Strip tag,
deatils on: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

```
strip_tags(get_the_excerpt());
```

Comment: Thank for your response. After fiddling with it, I found this work work:

`...&p[summary]=<?php echo get_the_content(); ?>&p[url]=<?php the_permalink(); ?>...`

Answer (score 0):

Saifuddin Sarker's answer is a good way to do it, another way to do it is:

[`wp_strip_all_tags( get_the_excerpt() );`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_strip_all_tags.)

Answer (score 0):

Escape WordPress's HTML characters in the_content();
is use:

```
ob_start();
the_content();

$old_content = ob_get_clean();

$new_content = strip_tags($old_content);

echo $new_content;
```